# Convert long to "byte-array-ed" text, without heap allocations

Tags: java, arrays, string, garbage-collection, long-integer

I would like to convert a (positive) primitive long to a `byte[]` in its textual form, in Java.

For example an easy way would be: `123 => "123" => [49, 50, 51]`

However converting long to `String` heap-allocates a `String` and I'm trying to avoid this for my GC-free library. I would rather render this directly on a pre-allocated byte array.

Hence, my question is how do I go directly from long to a `byte[]` representation, which if I call with a String constructor would (for the above example) given me "123". To clarify, I'm not looking to encode the long as a `byte[]` in binary form, but rather textual form.

Thanks!
N

Comment: That's a nice problem. Which character set?

Comment: It's irrelevant for my use case, let's say ASCII

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There aren't too many character sets that don't map the digits `0...9` to codes `48...57`

Comment: @biziclop Sure. But a character set that uses more bytes per character would need a bigger `byte[]`. Right?

Comment: Am I crazy or is the character set not super important here? What will you be doing with this `byte[]`? Writing it to a file? Will you be writing anything else to that file? How will you be reading it?

Comment: I don't understand your choices of answers. You asked for output into a pre-allocated byte-array, so you upvoted and accepted the answer that uses a non-pre-allocated byte array, and upvoted the answer that doesn't give you a byte array at all. You ignored the answers that actually did answer the question.

Comment: @Boann avoiding pre-allocation of byte arrays in the examples is trivial and I understand are for illustration purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple program:

```
long l = 123;
int size = (int)(Math.log10(l)+1);
byte[] array = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    long temp = (long) Math.pow(10, size - i - 1);
    array[i] = (byte) ((l / temp) + 48);
    l = l % temp;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // [49, 50, 51]
```

---

I have tested it for current time in milli-seconds as well and working as expected:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

output:

```
1406485727149
[49, 52, 48, 54, 52, 56, 53, 55, 50, 55, 49, 52, 57]
```

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for though. Besides, using `Math.pow()` to find the powers of 10 isn't the best of ideas, even though it works.

Comment: `int size = (int) l % 10;` this is wrong. It only works for n digit numbers ending in n.

Comment: @Eran No, I have tested it for 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567 etc. and works as expected.

Comment: Looks good for the input you tested, I tried long l = System.currentTimeMillis(), because my use-case is to store timestamps with this approach, and it doesn't seem to encode it properly just yet. +1 for now ;)

Comment: @user3218114 try 1230. 1234 works because it has 4 digits and ends with 4.

Comment: @Eran thanks for giving you valuable time. Now it's working using `int size = (int)(Math.log10(l)+1);`

Comment: Of course the `new byte[]` and `Arrays.toString()` creates quite a few objects, possibly more than just printing the long in the first place.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Aren't those there for testing purposes only?

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Arrays.toString()` is used just for display purpose. Not part of actual program. At least `byte[]` is expected as output.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, they are just for illustration purposes- I think I can easily avoid these, thanks also to biziclop & eran.

Answer (score 3):

To write it without using a byte[] or using Math.pow and Math.log which are pretty expensive you can do the following.

```
public static void toStream(OutputStream os, long l) throws IOException {
    toStream0(os, l / 10);
    os.write((int) ('0' + l % 10));
}

private static void toStream0(OutputStream os, long l) throws IOException {
    if (l == 0) return;
    toStream0(os, l / 10);
    os.write((int) ('0' + l % 10));
}

toStream(System.out, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

prints

```
1406486588664
```

If you are writing to a ByteBuffer, use `put(` or a StringBuilder use `append((char)`

You might consider larger bases to make the number smaller.

```
base 36: hy4p6ugr
base 16: 147791288bb
base 10: 1406485563579
```

Comment: +1 thanks for outputstream approach and explanation on base encoding savings!

Comment: @NT_ For a StringBuilder, you use `append((char) ...` and for ByteBuffer your use `put(...` instead of `write(...`

Comment: It's nice to have a solution using recursion too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're asking for (?):

```
static int toChars(long num, byte[] buffer) {
    if (num < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int length = 0;
    do {
        buffer[length++] = (byte)(num % 10 + '0');
    } while ((num /= 10) != 0);
    for (int i = 0, mid = length >> 1, j = length - 1; i < mid; i++, j--) {
        byte tmp = buffer[i];
        buffer[i] = buffer[j];
        buffer[j] = tmp;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Usage:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[19]; // 19 = enough for everything up to Long.MAX_VALUE

int length = toChars(51239827493284L, buffer);

System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, length,
    java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to avoid creating any objects. Can you write this without using `new` (or a method which does)

Comment: @PeterLawrey The `buffer` can avoid `new` by being static and used repeatedly. The String can't possibly avoid `new` because they're immutable.

Comment: You don't need to create a String to write a byte[] to an OutputStream ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey The question literally asks for something 'which if I call with a String constructor would (for the above example) given me "123"'. I demonstrated how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there's no trick to it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte [] result = new byte[6];
        convert( 123456, result );
        System.out.println( new String( result ) );
    }

    public static void convert( long n, byte [] array ) {
        for (int i = size( n ) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            array[i] = (byte)(n % 10 + '0');
            n = n / 10;
        }
    }

    public static int size( long n ) {
        int ret = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            ret++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Note that this only works for positive numbers and doesn't check whether the array is big enough to fit the number in, you should do both in real code. It can't handle the trivial case where `n=0` either.

You could avoid having to use the `size()` method by filling the array back to front, then flipping it around but I'm not quite sure it'd buy you anything performance-wise and it'd be a nightmare to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can preallocate your `byte[]` to the longest long (20 characters for the longest longs) and convert the long to string right into that array.

Of course, if you don't want to waste 20 characters on the number 17, you can quickly figure out the number of characters in the long (see if it's larger than 10^18, then if it's larger than 10^18, etc... You can do a binary search on the number of digits).